# Edit the value of a property in a listBox if selected?

Tags: c#, list, listbox, edit

I would like to allow the user to edit part of a listBox string through either double clicking and entering like a rename mode thing in the listBox or through a Message Box, which ever really. The value is a double and I want the result to be reflected in both the listBox and the actual list.

This is my list, I need to edit Cost:

```
        public BindingList<Edge> edgeList = new BindingList<Edge>();
```

This is my ToString Function:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Cost: {0}, Start: {1}, End: {2}", (int)_cost, _start, _end);
        }
```

This is adding to my list:

```
pfi.ni.edgeList.Add(e1);
```

And This is how I add new properties when they occur to my listBox:

```
listBox2.Items.Add(e1);
```

I have set up selectedIndexChanged event for my listBox and can get it so it shows me the cost of a property if clicked, it is now just editing it I guess.

```
    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Edge selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as Edge;

        result = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Cost: {0}", e1._cost));
        //selectedItem._cost doesn't work for some reason, so I use e1._cost 
        //until I can figure it out
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Edge selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as Edge;
selectedItem._cost = inputTextBox.Text;
listBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. At the moment, it is changing my cost to 1 in both my listBox and my lists so it is something, but it isn't changing to my inputted number. My cost is a double so I am converting like this:
    selectedItem._cost = Convert.ToDouble(MessageBox.Show(inputText.Text));

Comment: Nevermind, taking out MessageBox.Show solves this. I think it was returning 1 because maybe OK returns 1? I am not sure, but without the pop up, it works fine, cheers!